# Handling images with Typescript - NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, spoonacular

I have a simple site that fetches data from Spoonacular API and searches for ingredients, the response comes with a title and image. I have declared the types as:

```
export interface IProps {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
  }
```

So far my list of ingredients looks like:

```
const List = (props: { ingredient: IProps }) => {
  const { ingredient } = props;

  return (
    <Container>
      <Box>
        <Image src={ingredient.image} alt={ingredient.name} />
        <Box>
          {ingredient.name}
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default List;
```

I have removed everything related to styling up here FYI.

The props come from where I make the call:

```
const Search = () => {


  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState<IProps[]>([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/ingredients/search?query=${value}&number=2&apiKey=${URL}`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((data) => data.results)
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Flex justifyContent="center">
      <Flex direction="column">
        <Heading mb={6}>Search Recipe</Heading>
        <Input
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value}
          name="search"
          id="search"
          placeholder="Write here..."
          variant="filled"
          mb={2}
          type="text"
        />
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit} mb={5}>
          Search
        </Button>
       
      </Flex>
      {ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
        <List key={ingredient.id} ingredient={ingredient} />
      ))}
    </Flex>
  );
};
export default Search;
```

But what I don’t get is the fact that I get a 404 from the image:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/lemon.png
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 000.0.0.0:0000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Since I am new with typescript, I might have missed something quite basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what Ritik Mishra has said, and just as an example for you and other people using Spoonacular, your src would look like:

```
src={`https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_250x250/${ingredient.image}`}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is that the API is only giving you a filename like `lemon.png`. To locate the image from the API, you need to append it to the string `https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/` before passing  it into the `Image` component i.e in this case, you would end up with `https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/lemon.png`.

You can find more information about getting images from the API here [(link to Spoonacular API docs)](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Show-Images)